# Как в cURL получить refer url сайта отправившего запрос?

Tags: php

Есть два сайта, первый отправляет cURL post запрос на второй сайт.
Как на втором сайте получить url адрес (домен) первого сайта?
Помогите, пожалуйста.
Нужен именно домен без каких либо параметров.

Спасибо!

Comment: Пусть первый сайт отправляет при запросе дополнительный заголовок.

Answer (score 1):

Получить можно так:

```
$refer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
```

Вот тут вы можете прочитать про $_SERVER и все его индексы: http://php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.server.php